# Conexão com Azure - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, sql-server-2005, microsoft-azure

Estive tentando conectar no servidor de banco de dados do Microsoft Azure a uma aplicação codificada em .Net Framework que esta sendo executada em um **servidor windows 2003**.

O problema é que somente desse servidor é retornado falha, o seguinte:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)

Já validei:

- Dados da string de conexão

  - formato: `connectionString="Password=********; Encrypt=True; TrustServerCertificate=False; User ID=Name_Login; Initial Catalog=Name_Data_Base; Data Source=tcp:***********.database.windows.net,1433"/>`
- Possiveis bloqueios no Firewall

Vocês já tiveram erro semelhante? Se sim como foi tratado?

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde!
Chará!

Recentemente enfrentei um problema muito semelhante ao seu.

E após de muita dores de cabeçá para encontrar a solução, identifiquei que em meu servidor, o Firewall ainda estava bloqueando o IP de Saida e impossibilitando a conexão com o servidor do banco de dados no Azure.

Após configurar e liberar os IPs de forma adequada no Firewall, obtive com sucesso a comunicação entre meu servidor e o servidor do banco Azure